# the meaning of the expression "on the eye"

Tags: meaning, expressions, idioms

Can someone tell me what this expression means?

***"on the eye"***

> It accounts for the scene I witnessed in the barracks: after a particularly tasteless dinner, which was left uneaten by most of the soldiers, the unfortunate soldier, lying on his bed, the victim of a practical joke, loudly complained that he was still very hungry and wouldn’t mind a simple meal, perhaps ***a pair of eggs on the eye***

I found it in one of Slavoj Žižek's books and I would like to understand it.

Comment: Can you please add the whose sentence where the expression is used.

Comment: It accounts for the
scene I witnessed in the barracks: after a particularly tasteless
dinner, which was left uneaten by most of the soldiers,
the unfortunate soldier, lying on his bed, the victim
of a practical joke, loudly complained that he was still very
hungry and wouldn’t mind a simple meal, perhaps a pair of
eggs on the eye

Comment: Maybe "easy on the eyes" meaning pleasant looking?

Comment: i really have no idea. i looked everywhere xD

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the phrase is "eggs on the eye"

This is a translation of a Serbo-Croat phrase meaning fried eggs (not scrambled, but over easy in American)

But it is also a crude pun: like Spanish, Serbo-Croat uses "eggs" as a term for testicles.  So in "The Seven Veils of Fantasy" in Slavoj Zizek's *The Plague of Fantasies*, he explains the vulgar joke

> How do you make eggs on the eye? By putting the prick on the forehead!

i.e. by drawing a penis on a sleeping person's face